# Audio stops working when the computer comes out of standby or when I put a headset on the PC

Tags: audio

I have had an all in one for a long time, but I always encountered this problem with Linux (ubuntu and mint): Audio stops working when the computer comes out of standby or when I put a headset on the PC. I have dual boot and when I'm using Windows this problem doesn't happen. What should I do?

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LG product: 23V545-G.BK31P1 v: 0.1 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LG model: White Tip Mountain v: FAB3 serial: <filter> UEFI: Phoenix v: VIC2SF00 date: 04/21/2014 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-4200M bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Haswell rev: 3 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 19953 
           Speed: 909 MHz min/max: 800/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 897 2: 888 3: 809 4: 850 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: LG driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.0.4 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: LG driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-37-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: LG driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 
           bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Intel Wireless 3160 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 4000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 223.57 GiB used: 8.38 GiB (3.7%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37240G size: 223.57 GiB temp: 37 C 
           Optical-1: /dev/sr0 vendor: HL-DT-ST model: DVDRAM GA50N rev: 1.02 dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd,dvdrw 
           Features: speed: 24 multisession: yes audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r,dvd-ram state: running 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 109.15 GiB used: 8.34 GiB (7.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 59.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 240 Uptime: 9m Memory: 7.68 GiB used: 1.54 GiB (20.0%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 
           Shell: bash v: 5.0.16 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L.  What exactly does it mean "audio stops working"?  How do you diagnose this?  I have had a bit similar issues with audio sent to a different "sink", i.e. to a place like a monitor with no speakers.

Comment: If I am listening any music on YouTube or Spotfy the audio stops.